# ExpressJs middleware not working after import

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

This is my app.js

```
import path from 'path';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import express from 'express';

import defender from 'inflex-defend-api';

import { key, secret } from './config/app';

let apiDefender = defender(key, secret);

var app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(apiDefender.defend(false));

export default app;
```

A try import this app.js in server.js

```
import app from './app';

app.use('/v1.0', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('Request Type:', req.method)
    //next()
});
```

The '/v1.0' middleware not working if i use in server.js, but if i use in app.js, its good.

How can i use middleware out of app.js if i won't define them in routes.

For example (I dont want this):

```
app.post('/v1.0/api/ahri', function (req, res, next) { 
   console.log('Request Type:', req.method); 
   next(); 
}, function (req, res, next) {
   console.log('I know the request type');
});
```

Comment: It is unclear to me what exactly it is you are trying to do.  
Can you also include your server.js and how the example should be.

Comment: what is /v1.0 ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to use app.js in server.js (I assume this is your js where you define all the rest mappings), use server.js in app.js

**app.js**

```
import path from 'path';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import express from 'express';

import defender from 'inflex-defend-api';

import { key, secret } from './config/app';

let apiDefender = defender(key, secret);

var app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(apiDefender.defend(false));

require('./server)(app);

export default app;
```

**server.js**

```
module.exports = (app) => {
    app.use('/v1.0', function (req, res, next) {
        console.log('Request Type:', req.method)
        //next()
    });
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but i want get the app.js in another generated files

Comment: Infact you can also follow @Jesse Jay's solution and import it in all the files. Instead of importing app.js, just define var app=express(). But you will still have to require() them in your app.js

Comment: And if you need app in all other js files, you will have to do the same. No other way AFAIK.